# Access POST Request Value in FormValue Golang using POSTMAN

Tags: go, post, request, postman

I have no idea why I always receive an empty string when sending values in POSTMAN

```
func main(){
     rtr := mux.NewRouter()
     rtr.HandleFunc("/search", search).Methods("POST")
}
func search(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
     name := r.FormValue("name") //returns empty 

}
```

This is the body request in POSTMAN

[screenshot for the body request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k4O36.png)

```
{
   "name": "markus"


}
```

I tried to change the body request to form data

[Screenshot for form data in post request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2lAI0.png)

But it still didn't work.

Does anyone have a solution?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you have there is not a `FormValue` but a `JSON` body. If your JSON object is just a simple map of string to string, then you can do something like this:

```
func search(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {

    body, _ := ioutil.ReadAll(r.Body) // check for errors

    keyVal := make(map[string]string)
    json.Unmarshal(body, &keyVal) // check for errors

    name := keyVal["name"]

    // do whatever with name

}
```

**Edit**

If you need to parse a form value you need to call `ParseForm()`

```
func search(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {

    err := r.ParseForm()
    if err != nil {
        // handle err
    }

    name := r.FormValue("name")

}
```

Comment: I don't want to change the code. Does it mean that I should move the body request to form data  in POSTMAN? Check my code above, I have added more details.

Comment: Yes, check my edit for how you can parse the form request.

Answer (score 0):

Just want to share additional information here.

Please check the Content-Type in Header section of Postman if you are facing any problem in sending your request to the server.

- Set `Content-Type` to `application/json` for sending raw JSON in request.
- Set `Content-Type` to `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` if you are sending form values in request. Also select `x-www-form-urlencoded` in postman's Body section